# Dynamic Responsive Resize Images

Tags: html, css, media, responsive-design

I started working with responsive design and read that how to threat the images (dynamic):

```
.midiv { width: 300px; float: left; }

.midiv img { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }
```

But when i load the website it show's the full size of the image, after full site download it fits the div's size.

Im using this too in the header area:

```
js/modernizr-2.0.6.js
js/css3-mediaqueries.js
```

what could be wrong in my way of doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hard to determine exactly whats wrong with your code base, would help to see your HTML as well.

Generally I would set your .midiv to have a max-width:300px and then set your .midiv img to have display:inline.